# How do you configure cmake to only rebuild changed .java files in a java project?

Tags: java, cmake

I have a cmake project that looks like:

```
project(myProject JAVA)
add_library(myLibrary foo.java bar.java)
```

but when I run make in the directory, all the java files are rebuilt, even if they weren't changed. Is there a way to turn off that behavior?

Thanks,

Comment: I am curious, why would building all the java files be a problem?  What is the root issue here?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer to your question, but...: why are you using cmake for your Java project? There are tools such as Apache Ant and Apache Maven which are the de-facto standard build tools for Java projects.

Comment: jzd - Basically, I'm getting into the range of ~40 java files in this project, and rebuilding it each time I make one change is becoming time consuming

Comment: Jesper - this is a portion of a multiple-language project. If it was pure-java, I'd use maven, but there's a number of language bindings as well. There'd be a bit of an impedance mismatch to use a different buildtool just for java.

Comment: put the @ symbol before the name of the user and Jesper or I will get a notification that you have replied to us, otherwise the only way we will see is if we visit this question again.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `add_library` Java support in CMake is not too hot. It ignores the "package" directive, and assume that "foo.java" creates "foo.class" in the base directory, not in a sub-directory `com/example/` for `package com.example;`.

If you look at the generated makefiles in `CMakeFiles/<jar_file>.dir/build.make`, it has code like this (cleaned up a bit)

```
CMakeFiles/test.dir/foo.class: ../foo.java
    javac  $(Java_FLAGS) /full/path/to/foo.java -d CMakeFiles/test.dir
```

This is a broken dependency when foo.java contains "package com.example;" at the top. Make expects foo.class to be created, when it isn't and you run make again, it will compile foo.java to see if maybe this time it will work. The actual file generated is in com/example (which luckily gets added to the final jar file).

The good news is that things have improved recently. In version 2.8.6 of CMake a new module was added called `UseJava` that does a much better job of compiling Java files and correctly rebuilding when there are changes. Instead of using `add_library` you need to use `add_jar`. Here is a complete example CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
find_package(Java)
include(UseJava)
project(java_test Java)
set(SRC
    src/com/example/test/Hello.java
    src/com/example/test/Message.java
)
add_jar(hello ${SRC})
```

That will produce hello.jar from the input source files.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is to just build the entire Java project.   If you change one class and just recompile it, how will cmake know to compile another class that depended on it.  What happens if you remove a method in one class that others depend on, skipping recompiling the other classes will give you run-time errors instead of a compiler error.

However, 40 java files is a small amount and it seems like they should compile in seconds or less.